# Ajax Template Silverstripe Widget

Tags: silverstripe

I have added a widget to a Page with a class of Page. The widget php code returns a PaginatedList and it is successfully rendering in my Page.ss template using the $SidebarView tag.

How can I hijack the pagination click to have the widget rendered with a new template? I assume that testing for is_ajax on the index method and doing a $this->renderWith('myTemplate') is not going to work since I only want to render the widget with the new template, not the whole page.

Here is my current Page.php code drawing from Zauberfisch's original answer:

```
public function index( SS_HTTPRequest $request ) {
    $page = $this->data();

    if ( $request->isAjax() ) {
        $widgetArea = $page->Sidebar();
        $widget = $widgetArea->Widgets()->filter( 'ClassName', 'ScbWidget' );
        return $widget->renderWith( 'ScbTemplate' );
        } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

and here is my widget php code that returns the paginated list to my template:

```
public function ScbList() {
    $list = new PaginatedList( CatalogItem::get()->filter( array( 'SchoolChoirRelease' => 1 ) ), Controller::curr()->getRequest() );
    $list->setPageLength( $this->ShowPerPage );
    return $list;
}
```

When the paginated list is returned to the template without ajax, everything works as expected - ?start=2 returns the list offset by 2 items. When I hijack the link and render the widget using the new template, my list is not being rendered in the new template. Here is my js:

```
ajaxify = function( href, callback ) {
    $.ajax( {
        url: href,
        success: function( data ) {
            callback( data );
        }
    });
};

hijackSubmit = function() {
    jqueryMap.$pagination.on( 'click', 'a', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $( this ).attr( 'href' );

        ajaxify( href, function( data ) {
          jqueryMap.$container.html( data );
        } );
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SilverStripe any object of type `ViewableData` can be rendered. Page is a subclass of `ViewableData`, but so is `Widget`. A lot of objects in SilverStripe extend `ViewableData`.

This means you are already on the right track.
I am assuming you have 2 variables:

- `$request` a request object of type `SS_HTTPRequest`
  (if you are in a Controller, you can get it like this: `$request = $this->getRequest()`)
- `$page` a page object of type `Page` or subclass.
  (if you are in a Controller, you can get it like this: `$page = $this->data()`)

now you should be able to do:

```
if ($request->isAjax()) {
    $widgetArea = $page->SideBar();
    $widget = $widgetArea->Widgets()->filter('ClassName', 'MyWidget')->First();
    return $widget->renderWith('MyWidgetTemplate');
}
// do something else
```

---

NOTE: if `$request->isAjax()` is never true, add `?ajax=1` to the URL when you call it in javascript. `?ajax=1` will let SilverStripe know that this is an ajax request.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. The widget is rendering with the correct template now, but I noticed that the request is not hitting my method on the widget that returns my paginated list, so the template is returning blank and not recognizing any template variables associated with my paginated list. Do I need to recreate my list in the index method on Page.php capturing the start variable and using it as my offset?

Comment: I assume so. I never used widgets so I don't know. Perhaps you could paste your code, that might help me understand what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Zauberfisch, I have added code to better explain what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: This is all in an attempt to avoid creating a new page just to have a separate template and is inspired by chillu's slides at http://chillu.com/docs/silverstripe-pagetypeitis/#/1

Comment: If there is a more elegant way to accomplish having a my ScbList paginated list be available to only certain pages using Page.php as its model and Page.ss template I would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: looking at your code now, I see nothing wrong with it at first glance. my first guess would be that there is some problem passing the request to the widget (that `Controller::curr()->getRequest()` for some odd reason is not what it should be). Have you tried debugging if there is a difference between `$request` in Page.php and `Controller::curr()->getRequest()` in the widget?

Comment: I believe the issue was that `$widget = $widgetArea->Widgets()->filter( 'ClassName', 'ScbWidget' )` was returning a HasManyList. When I filtered it down by First(), the template is using the $list variable.

Comment: ah, right. my mistake, sorry. will fix it in the answer.